# Error When Editing Membership Types

Tags: wordpress, civimember

Running CiviCRM 4.7.31 on WordPress 4.9.5. When attempting to edit an existing membership type, I am receiving an error "Network Error: Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." I refresh and get the same result. All other parts of CiviCRM are working fine. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is this a regular instance or multisite?

Comment: Hi Andy. Regular instance. No multisite

Comment: Did you set CiviCRM in Debug mode? If not, enable it and report if there were any extra messages and/or the content of any created error log file

Comment: Please  also check browser's JS console to have a glance at ajax errors.

Answer (score 1):

With such issues it is worth trying a 'right click' on the link to open the Edit screen as you may get to see an error message that you don't see with the pop up. If you find one, the repost in your Q

Comment: Hi, when I 'right click' on the link to edit the membership type, I get this error message : "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Constraint Violation - membership_contact_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for Membership,get API. If so, please raise a bug report."

Comment: You could take a look in your ConfigAndLog files, or if that is trickier for you than adding an Extension you could add the Log Viewer extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer - and see if that gives you more info

Comment: I get the exact same error when I try to edit a membership. I am also running Civi 4.7.31 on Wordpress. Right clicking and opening in a new window, gives me "Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Contribute_Task::taskTitles() in /home/mysite/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Task.php on line 163" Has there been any luck with finding the root cause?

Comment: unless you can show that this problem is still occuring on latest civicrm then it is unlikely effort is being put in to finding a fix for an older version of civicrm

Comment: also confirm if you have any warnings/errors eg Resource urls etc